# Pentaho/Javascript: How to change field value(unitPrice) from negative integer to postive integer?

Tags: javascript, database, pentaho

In Pentaho program, using Modified javascript step. Using product.csv file, in unitPrice field, some integer had positive and some other are negative. In javascript, how do I type in there?

Here the example I typed so far and still an error.

```
 if(unitPrice.getInteger() < 0)
{
    unitPrice.setValue(var) = Math.abs(unitPrice.getInteger());
}
```

Comment: No idea about 'Pentaho', but my guess is `unitPrice.setValue(Math.abs(unitPrice.getInteger()))`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use code as thg435 suggested:

   unitPrice.setValue(abs(unitPrice));
2. Check 'Compatibility mode' in 'Modified Java Script Value' component.

Regards
Mateusz